# Why the cost of seq2seq become more and more larger

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I've tried to use tensorflow to complete the basic seq2seq model to summary the documents without tf.contrib exist module. After I finished this model and started to train it, I found that the cost became more and more larger, finally it became nan. It is a very strange phenomena because I've used clipped gradient optimizer to optimize the cost. The prediction of this model is also strange, every prediction sequence is the same as the previous. Anyone can help me, thank you very much!
Here is the log:

```
Epoch: 1, Batch: 9660, Sample: 309088, Loss: 10501.7
Epoch: 1, Batch: 9661, Sample: 309120, Loss: 12208.6
Epoch: 1, Batch: 9662, Sample: 309152, Loss: 10829.7
Epoch: 1, Batch: 9663, Sample: 309184, Loss: nan
Epoch: 1, Batch: 9664, Sample: 309216, Loss: nan


Title: ['<START>', 'Seahawks', 'sign', 'former', 'Minnesota', 'kicker', 'Blair', 'Walsh', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END      >', '<END>']
Pred: ['<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<      START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>']
Title: ['<START>', 'Redskins', 'WR', 'DeSean', 'Jackson', 'Packers', 'LB', 'Clay', 'Matthews', 'active', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>', '<END>',       '<END>']
Pred: ['<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<      START>', '<START>', '<START>', '<START>']
```

And here is my code of tensorflow:

```
def model(argv):
batch_size = 32
vocab_size = 100000
emb_size = 200
input_words_size = 500
output_words_size = 20
min_input_size = 100
encoder_hidden_unit = 512
encoder_rnn_layer = 3
encoder_keep_prob = 1.0
decoder_hidden_unit = 512
decoder_rnn_layer = 3
decoder_keep_prob = 1.0
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        with tf.name_scope('input_layer'):
            embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
                tf.float32, [vocab_size, emb_size], 'emb_holder')
            input_idx_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
                tf.int64, [None, input_words_size], 'input_idx')
            output_idx_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
                tf.int64, [None, output_words_size], 'output_idx')
            output_idx_swap_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
                tf.int64, [output_words_size-1, None], 'output_idx_swap')
            masking_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
                tf.float32, [output_words_size-1, None], 'masking'
            )

        with tf.name_scope('pre-train_embedding'):
            emb_weight = tf.Variable(tf.constant(
                0.0, shape=[vocab_size, emb_size]), trainable=False, name='emb_W')
            embedding_init = emb_weight.assign(embedding_placeholder)

        with tf.name_scope('embedding_layer'):
            encoder_embedding_out = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_weight, input_idx_placeholder)
            decoder_embedding_out = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_weight, output_idx_placeholder)

        with tf.name_scope('gen_decoder_input_list'):
            target_label = tf.unstack(output_idx_swap_placeholder)
            target_masking = tf.unstack(masking_placeholder)

    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        with tf.name_scope('encoder'):
            encoder_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(encoder_hidden_unit)
            encoder_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
                encoder_rnn_cell, output_keep_prob=encoder_keep_prob)
            encoder = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([encoder_rnn_cell] * encoder_rnn_layer)
            encoder_init_state = encoder.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
            encoder_outputs = []
            encoder_state = encoder_init_state
            with tf.variable_scope('encoder_rnn'):
                for i in xrange(input_words_size):
                    if i > 0:
                        tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
                    (rnn_output, encoder_state) = encoder(encoder_embedding_out[:, i, :], encoder_state)
                    encoder_outputs.append(rnn_output)
            # encoder_output = encoder_outputs[-1]
            encoder_final_state = encoder_state

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        with tf.name_scope('decoder'):
            decoder_b = tf.get_variable(
                "decoder_bias", shape=[vocab_size], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
            decoder_weight = tf.get_variable(
                "decoder_weight",
                shape=[decoder_hidden_unit, vocab_size],
                initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
            decoder_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(decoder_hidden_unit)
            decoder_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(decoder_rnn_cell,
                                                             output_keep_prob=decoder_keep_prob)
            decoder = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([decoder_rnn_cell] * decoder_rnn_layer)
            # decoder_init_state = decoder.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
            decoder_init_state = encoder_final_state
            decoder_outputs = []
            decoder_state = decoder_init_state
            decoder_pred_state = decoder_init_state
            decoder_pred_outputs = []
            result = []
            with tf.variable_scope('decoder_rnn'):
                for i in xrange(output_words_size):
                    if i > 0:
                        tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
                    (rnn_output, decoder_state) = decoder(decoder_embedding_out[:, i, :], decoder_state)
                    decoder_outputs.append(rnn_output)
                for i in xrange(output_words_size):
                    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
                    if i == 0:
                        (pred_output, decoder_pred_state) = decoder(
                            decoder_embedding_out[:, i, :], decoder_pred_state)
                    else:
                        (pred_output, decoder_pred_state) = decoder(decoder_pred_outputs[-1], decoder_pred_state)
                    pred_logit = tf.matmul(pred_output, decoder_weight) + decoder_b
                    pred_result = tf.argmax(pred_logit, 1)
                    result.append(pred_result)
                    pred_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_weight, pred_result)
                    decoder_pred_outputs.append(pred_emb)

    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        with tf.name_scope('train_gpu'):
            train_seq = decoder_outputs[:-1]
            train_logits = [tf.matmul(i, decoder_weight) + decoder_b for i in train_seq]
            log_prep_list = []
            for logit, target, masking in zip(train_logits, target_label, target_masking):
                target = tf.reshape(target, [-1])
                masking = tf.reshape(masking, [-1])
                crossent = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                    labels=target, logits=logit
                )
                log_prep_list.append(crossent * masking)
            log_preps = tf.add_n(log_prep_list)
            cost = tf.reduce_sum(log_preps)
            # train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
            gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
            capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1., 1.), var) for grad, var in gvs]
            train = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)
            # target_seq = decoder_embedding_out[:, 1:, :]

        with tf.name_scope('initial'):
            init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    vector_file = argv[1]
    rank_file = argv[2]
    emb_size = int(argv[3])
    train_file = argv[4]
    epoch = int(argv[5])
    valid_list = gen_top_N_list(vocab_size, rank_file)
    word_idx, idx_word, emb_mat = gen_emb_mat(vector_file, emb_size, valid_list)

    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(embedding_init, feed_dict={embedding_placeholder: emb_mat})
    del emb_mat
    for ep in xrange(epoch):
        f = open(train_file, 'r')
        cnt = 0
        train_content = []
        train_title = []
        train_masking = []
        for line in f:
            data = json.loads(line.strip())
            title_list = tokenize(data['title'])
            content_list = tokenize(data['content'])
            if len(title_list) > output_words_size - 2 \
                    or len(content_list) > input_words_size \
                    or len(content_list) < min_input_size:
                continue
            title_list.insert(0, '<START>')
            title_masking = [1.0] * (len(title_list) + 1)
            title_masking.extend([0.0] * (output_words_size - 1 - len(title_list)))
            title_list.extend(['<END>'] * (output_words_size - len(title_list)))
            content_list.extend(['<END>'] * (input_words_size - len(content_list)))
            train_content.append([word_idx.get(i, word_idx['<unk>']) for i in content_list])
            train_title.append([word_idx.get(i, word_idx['<unk>']) for i in title_list])
            train_masking.append(title_masking)
            cnt += 1
            if cnt % batch_size == 0:
                batch = cnt / batch_size
                batch_train_content = np.array(train_content)
                batch_train_title = np.array(train_title)
                batch_swap_train_title = batch_train_title.swapaxes(0, 1)[1:]
                batch_train_masking = np.array(train_masking).swapaxes(0, 1)[1:]
                if batch % 100 == 0:
                    loss, res, _ = sess.run(
                        [cost, result, train], feed_dict={
                            input_idx_placeholder: batch_train_content,
                            output_idx_placeholder: batch_train_title,
                            output_idx_swap_placeholder: batch_swap_train_title,
                            masking_placeholder: batch_train_masking})
                    out = np.array(res).swapaxes(0, 1).tolist()
                    for i in xrange(len(out)):
                        label_seq = [idx_word[j] for j in batch_train_title[i].tolist()]
                        pred = [idx_word[j] for j in out[i]]
                        print "Title: " + str(label_seq) + "\nPred: " + str(pred)
                else:
                    loss, _ = sess.run(
                        [cost, train], feed_dict={
                            input_idx_placeholder: batch_train_content,
                            output_idx_placeholder: batch_train_title,
                            output_idx_swap_placeholder: batch_swap_train_title,
                            masking_placeholder: batch_train_masking})
                    print 'Epoch: ' + str(ep + 1) + ', Batch: ' + str(batch + 1) + \
                          ', Sample: ' + str(cnt) + ', Loss: ' + str(loss)
                train_content = []
                train_title = []
                train_masking = []
        f.close()
```

Comment: Can you try a learning rate of 0.001 ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to adjust the learning rate to 0.001, but it still became nan after 4000 batches trainning